# How can I edit Nodegroup in AWS EKS from AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-cdk

I use AWS CDK to create eks cluster then use `addNodegroupCapacity` to add nodegroup.

```js
    const myNodeGroup = cluster.addNodegroupCapacity('my-node-group', {
      nodegroupName: 'my-node-group',
      instanceTypes: [
        new ec2.InstanceType('t3a.small'), 
      ],
      minSize: 1,
      desiredSize: 1,
      maxSize: 1,
      diskSize: 10,
      capacityType: eks.CapacityType.SPOT,
      amiType: eks.NodegroupAmiType.AL2_X86_64,
      subnets: { subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC },
    })
```

I want to change subnet to

```js
    subnets: { availabilityZones: ['ap-southeast-1a'] }
```

When I made change in CDK I got an error

```
    Resource handler returned message: "NodeGroup already exists with name my-node-group and cluster name  (Service: Eks, Status Code: 409, Request ID: {Request ID})" (RequestToken: {RequestToken}, HandlerErrorCode: AlreadyExists)
```

How can I edit this nodegroup from AWS CDK or I have to delete and recreate it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the subnet is a [replacement operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-eks-nodegroup.html#aws-resource-eks-nodegroup-properties), which means the NodeGroup will be destroyed and another created.  However, your explicit `nodegroupName` is interfering with this CloudFormation process.  For this reason it's best practice to [use generated resource names, not physical names](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/best-practices.html#best-practices-apps-names).

Delete the resource manually.  Remove the `nodegroupName` prop to avoid this problem in the future.